# TensorFlow input data protocol buffer (tf.train.Example) TypeError for Feature with string type

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to encode my data as [tf.train.Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) according to tensorflow's [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data).
I have a string value that I want to pass to the `Features` property of the `Example` class and I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_example = tf.train.Example()
s1 = "sample string 1"
tf_example.features.feature['str1'].bytes_list.value.extend([s1])
```

However, I get the error that it is expecting `bytes` not `str`:

```
TypeError: 'sample string 1' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: ((<class 'bytes'>,),)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they expect `s1` to be a byte string, so you need to add `b` before the `"`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_example = tf.train.Example()
s1 = b"sample string 1"
tf_example.features.feature['str1'].bytes_list.value.extend([s1])
```